# How do I make a new OEM Install?

Tags: oem

I'm very new to linux and I got a second laptop with ubuntu preinstalled but when I did a fresh OEM install my computer ran out of battery and shutdown but when I tried to make another OEM install the option was not there anymore.

How do I make another OEM Installation?

Comment: If you are "new to Linux", then why are you doing OEM installs instead of ordinary installs? Are you an OEM?

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; so we'd be limited to guessing anyway.  Ubuntu has *five* different installers available for use, selected by the release/ISO used, and given we have no idea which you tried to use, we cannot even know which *installer* you're using (at least one doesn't offer OEM)

Answer (score 0):

You already installed Ubuntu halfway and the installation failed. If you really were the OEM you could boot the laptop with your own special OEM installation media and try again, but you're not an original equipment manufacturer so you don't get a second chance. Fortunately the correct Ubuntu installation type for you is the ordinary non-OEM Ubuntu installation option anyway. You can use the *Try Ubuntu* option of the Ubuntu installation media to test if everything works in an Ubuntu live session before committing to installing Ubuntu on your laptop.